# Changing page title via route from multiple config.js files in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have an angular app that loads different locations which should all have different page titles. I've seen many posts of how showing how to do if from the route, but my route actually pulls location data from config files that contain specific data for each location.

Can someone direct me to a Technique that will facilitate this when using values from an object in the config file?

Comment: Routes should be provided at config time, not during run-time. What do you mean by `location data`?

Comment: which routing mechanism are you using?

Comment: Locations meaning the app contains different view includes for different business locations. Each location is a separate entity and therefore has its own title and custom includes. When loading each location's includes, the pagetitle stays the same as what is in the index.html. I need to load a title according to each different business location by regionId. I'm using ngRoute as the routing mechanism. Each location's custom information is handled through a config.js file that is specific to each location. I'll be adding a snippet above to show.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post the answer to this. My Route pointed to a config file that loaded different stylesheets, location information, Hours, Phone Numbers etc. In order to pull custom page title for each of the locations, the title had to live in the config.js file. The config file contained a AppConfig object that was declared outside of the scope angular so it is available anywhere in the app. Then I called that value into the parent app controller and set title using ng-bind="title". This will also allow for all other locations to have separate page title just by calling their config.js.